# what kind of Recurrent Neural Network should I use to model solar irradiance data?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-events

I am trying to model solar irradiance data. I have data per minute for like 6 months. Naturally during the night solar irradiance = 0 and over the day it creases and then drecreases. I have many data about 400,000 observations.

The main problem is what kind of **architecture and type** of Neural Network should I use? I would like to predict 1 day in advance what the next day is going to be like.

A day is 1440 observation (60 * 24).
I am using keras, on python. Any ideas/ input on how to approach this problem?

Hereby a graph of the data.

[image: solar irradiance per minute]

Comment: Is the irradiance the only input that you have or do you have other types of measures? And do you necessairly have to use RNN for your prediction?

Answer (score 0):

I think using a RNN is necessary for your dataset. You should definitely try out LSTM and GRU networks. You basically input the current observation, and it will output the value of the next observation. If you want to predict 1440 observations ahead, you input the last known observation, which will give you the next observation - and you input this again, repeat this process 1440 times.

However keep in mind, the lstm will *not* be able to detect patterns that occurred in other seasons than your measurements. 400000 samples seems a lot, but not if you're doing research about the sun - which has an annual pattern, 6 months won't cover the entire cyclus.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I just tried this but the RNN is not catching the pattern. Do you suggest just a simple structure with 1 input like 1-2-1 where 1 (input) - 2 (lstm layer) -  1 output layer ? or something more complex?